# how to extract formating part from a string

Tags: c#, regex

How does one extract only the formatting part from a string. For example:
if I have a string = "Warning: the error {0} has occurred. {1, 9} module has {2:0%} done."
I would like to extract {0}, {1,9} and {2:0%} out into a sting array.  Is there a regular expression or something that can be done other than my way of looping the string with Substring indexof '{' and  '}' alternately?

Answer (score 1):

Will some variant of "\{[^}]+\}" not work?  Run it through finding the matches and substring'ing out from start to end of the match.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is different from other answers in that it uses non-greedy matching (".*?"):

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        const string input = "Warning: the error {0} has occurred. {1, 9} module has {2:0%} done.";
        const string pattern = "{.*?}"; // NOTE: "?" is required here (non-greedy matching).
        var formattingParts = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Where(item => item.Success).Select(item => item.Groups[0].Value);
        foreach (var part in formattingParts) {
            Console.WriteLine(part);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 I'd started writing something with named matches to help extract each part individually, but the above stopped me - really nice solution

Comment: Except doing [^}] in between { and } prevents it from being greedy.  Likewise on [0-9:,% .] that Jordan proposed.  Ethan's is the only greedy one that will match "{0} ... {1}" from beginning to end.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Regex(@"\{[0-9:,% .]+\}");
```

You may have to tweak/tune it to account for any additional formatting options that you haven't provided in your example.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class takes a regex and will return all matching sub-strings.

For example:

```
String str = "Warning: the error {0} has occurred. {1, 9} module has {2:0%} done.";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( "{.*}");
while (matcher.find()){
    String matched = matcher.group()
    \\do whatever you want with matched
}
```